# I try to move to another activity by using the spinner items

Tags: android, spinner, onclicklistener

When I run the application and try to click an a item don't change nothing. It show me the mainactivity and can't go to the second. I already import all the classes in the manifest. Where i wrong? This is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {


Spinner spinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    spinner= (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Alloggi, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            }






        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });






    final VideoView videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    String urlpath = "android.resource://" + getPackageName()+ "/" + R.raw.videopol;
    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(urlpath));
    videoView.start();






    }



@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}





@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    System.err.println("**************" + position);

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Casalini.class);
            i.setClass(this, Casalini.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case 1:
            Intent ir = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Bungalow.class);
            ir.setClass(this, Bungalow.class);
            startActivity(ir);
            break;
        case 2:
            Intent ic = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Villette.class);
            ic.setClass(this, Villette.class);
            startActivity(ic);
            break;
        case 3:
            Intent it = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Deluxe.class);
            it.setClass(this,Deluxe.class);
        case 4:
            Intent iz = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Camping.class);
            iz.setClass(this, Camping.class);

}

    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() + " selected ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
```

}

**This is my second activity**

`
public class Casalini extends MainActivity {

```
ImageView im;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_casalini);
}

public void biggerView (View v) {

  im=(ImageView)  findViewById(R.id.selected);
    switch (v.getId())

    {
        case R.id.image1:im.setImageResource(R.drawable.casalini);
            break;
        case R.id.image2:im.setImageResource(R.drawable.casalini1);
            break;
        case R.id.image3:im.setImageResource(R.drawable.casalini2);
            break;
        case R.id.image4:im.setImageResource(R.drawable.casalini3);
            break;
        case R.id.image5:im.setImageResource(R.drawable.casalini4);
            break;



    }


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}
`

Answer (score 0):

in this function

```
 @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
Intent intent  =  new Intent(getApplicationContext(), secondActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
            }
```

Add an intent to your seconde activity

Comment: Still don't working... It can be a problem because in the MainActivity i've inserted a video without ( start, stop ) buttons? I don't know what I can do. I've tried all I know :(

Comment: Sorry I'm in work now, I 'll check your code when I go home.